# Histogram Calculation in opencv

Tags: opencv

I don't understand arguments we pass in "cvCalcHist". do someone has sample code ? or any description . I have read the documentation but unable to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the C++ tutorials: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html#histogram-calculation

Check the Python tutorials: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_table_of_contents_histograms/py_table_of_contents_histograms.html#table-of-content-histograms